# Trying to remember a C code utility that shrinks gcc output to a 1-liner unless there is an error

Tags: gcc, output, trim

Some 10-15 years back I had used an open source utility that hides all gcc output for a file compilation unless there is an error. I can't remember the name of the command / utility. You had to use it in the Makefile via CXX / CPP flags, just like distcc or ccache.

Sample output where the file compiles successfully

```
Compiling aes-ctr.c                              ... [ok]
```

[looks a bit like the gentoo openrc init process that prints ok]

Sample output where the file fails to compile

```
gcc -I/usr/include -L/usr/lib -l math aes-ctr.c
Include directory '/usr/include' does not exist
Other nested gcc error messages
More gcc error messages...
...
```

I did quite a bit of Googling and Stackoverflow searching but could not locate the utility. If anyone could help me remember what this utility was, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

PS: I distinctly remember that it was C code that had to be first compiled (maybe from openssl or gentoo?), and not colorgcc.pl.

Answer (score 0):

The utility is called ccdv

It is now hosted @ https://github.com/IngwiePhoenix/ccdv-rmx

From the help file :

> $ ccdv
>
> Usage: ccdv /path/to/cc CFLAGS...
>
> I wrote this to reduce the deluge Make output to make finding actual problems easier. It is intended to be invoked from Makefiles, like this.
>
> Instead of:

```
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEFS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -c
```

> Rewrite your rule so it looks like:

```
.c.o:
    @ccdv $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEFS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -c
```

It was earlier hosted @ https://sourceforge.net/projects/ccdv/